# Why am I receiving this error message? "An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server"

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I get the following error when trying to launch my windows application in another machine.

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (Provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL
>   Server)."

In my machine the app is working but in the user's machine it doesn't work. I have tried a lot of solutions whether in stackoverflow or another website, where none of them helped me to solve this problem. The database is local, so i'm not using any servers or something like that. And the strange thing is that the Log in form is actually working but the other forms are not working. This is a code from one of the forms that are not working to make the idea closer. I hope that you can help me to solve this problem cause I am really running out of time. I'm using VB.NET and SQL SERVER.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form13
    'Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection("database=Leave_manager;server=(local);integrated security=true")
    Private Sub Form13_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: cette ligne de code charge les données dans la table 'Leave_managerDataSet1.Addemployees'. Vous pouvez la déplacer ou la supprimer selon vos besoins.
        Me.AddemployeesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Leave_managerDataSet1.Addemployees)
    End Sub
    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Try
            cn.Open()
            Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand("select Fname,Lname from Addemployees where ID = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "'", cn)
            Dim myreader As SqlDataReader
            myreader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()
            myreader.Read()
            If myreader.HasRows Then
                TextBox2.Text = myreader.Item("Fname").ToString
                TextBox1.Text = myreader.Item("Lname").ToString
            End If
            cn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error while connecting to SQL Server." & ex.Message)
        Finally
            cn.Close()
        End Try
        Try
            cn.Open()
            Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT Leave_num FROM Addemployees WHERE ID='" & ComboBox1.Text & "'", cn)
            Dim myreader1 As SqlDataReader
            myreader1 = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()
            myreader1.Read()
            If myreader1.HasRows Then
                TextBox6.Text = myreader1.Item("Leave_num").ToString
            End If
            cn.Close()
        Catch
            MessageBox.Show("Error!", "exit", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox2.Clear()
    TextBox3.Clear()
    TextBox4.Clear()
    TextBox6.Clear()
    Me.CheckBox1.Checked = False
    Me.Hide()
    Form6.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to Restore is record?", "Record", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
        Try
            cn.Open()
            Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
            Dim RA As Integer
            cmd = New SqlCommand("update Addemployees set Leave_num ='" & TextBox3.Text & "'  where ID='" & ComboBox1.Text & "' ", cn)
            cmd.Connection = cn
            RA = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Process successful!", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            cn.Close()
        Catch
            MessageBox.Show("Error!", "exit", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to Restore all records?", "Record", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
        If Me.TextBox4.ReadOnly = False Then
            Try
                cn.Open()
                Dim cmd2 As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
                Dim Rb As Integer
                cmd2 = New SqlCommand("update Addemployees set Leave_num ='" & TextBox4.Text & "'", cn)
                cmd2.Connection = cn
                Rb = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MessageBox.Show("Process successful!", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                cn.Close()
            Catch
                MessageBox.Show("Error!", "exit", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try
        ElseIf Me.TextBox4.ReadOnly = True Then
            MessageBox.Show("Error!, please select selectr all option", "exit", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox2.Clear()
    TextBox3.Clear()
    TextBox4.Clear()
    TextBox6.Clear()
    Me.CheckBox1.Checked = False

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If Me.CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        Me.TextBox4.ReadOnly = False
    ElseIf Me.CheckBox1.Checked = False Then
        Me.TextBox4.ReadOnly = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub
```

End Class`

Comment: You need to be suspicious of the sql connection string.  The error is in the connection and will be related to the connection string (assuming SQL is available and connecting as you seemed to have proven.)

Comment: yeah, and i'm totally lost at this stage. what should i do

Comment: @OuallaWalid We can't guess from here, but you have to check your sql connection string, also check if the server is runing.

Comment: I have checked the connection string a lot of times as well as the server but everything is correct

Comment: I would suggest you create a new form, just stripped down to what you need to connect to SQL just to prove that works, or get it working.  Then build from there.  If needed start with the connection code from the working form.  This may highlight what is going on.

Comment: Can you connect to that same database using those same connection details via Management Studio?

Comment: @GlennHolden I'll try your suggestion And reply

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes, and in my machine works good. But in the user's machine no

Comment: So you can connect to the database using SSMS on both your machine and this other user's machine?  Your connection string is specifying that the database is attached to a default instance on the same machine as the application. Is that the case for this other user or are they supposed to be connecting to a database on a different machine?

Comment: Of course, The user use his own machine. And the database is included in each machine (manually),

Comment: @jmcilhinney And the user when he enter the password and username, the application works and he moves to the next form where the problem  occures. I have checked the connection string many times and it is correct, so i have no clue

Comment: You talk about the user entering a username and password but your connection string specifically states that it's using integrated security so I still don't know if you really are telling us what we need to know.

Comment: @jmcilhinney When i was talking about the password i was referring to the application not the database. Because the application needs to connect with the DB to verify the password . But the use the other functions of the application like adding New employee or restoring the data this problem occures. I hope that i have made the idea clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The error - "(Provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)" points out to configuration error on SQL Server part.  Please check and ensure that the server accepts connections through named pipes.
2. "In my machine the app is working but in the user's machine it doesn't work." .......a) Please check the firewall for access of port 1433 (or any other defined port),
   b) Please go to services on the user's machine, restart 'SQL Server'
   c) In services itself, restart 'Windows firewall', if required.
3. "And the user when he enter the password and username, the application works and he moves to the next form where the problem occures."..Seems each of your form requires authentication.
4. I suggest you to take off the database from the user's machine, move to yours, provide access to the user's machine and test from user's machine.  You need to create a SQL server user (and not as a windows user for remote machine) and test it.  I believe this should take care of DB connectivity issue.

Comment: Thank you very much that was very helpful , and the last one is working for me

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your sqlserver version.
Check your server name just open cmd and type `SQLCMD -L`.
Check your server instance name `sqllocaldb i`.

In sql server express 2012 normally instance name is `(LocalDB)\v11.0`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and support